# How to use QTimer to get data from an external peripheral device for a specific time interval only?

Tags: qt

**Aim**:

I am working on Qt Creator and want to interface Modem with my main program 
, for that, I need to fetch the data from the modem for a specific time interval (say `3` seconds) only and after that I have to stop receiving data.

**My Work**:
I tried to implement it using:

```
QTimer::singleShot(3000,this,SLOT(SLOT1()));
```

But the limitation with it:
 It calls the `SLOT1` after `3000` m sec, but this is not what I want.

**My requirement**:
 is to use timer in order to fetch data for `3` seconds only and then stop.

Comment: You can have 2 timers, one for starting the data fetching and the other to stop it. Might that solve your issue?

Comment: How exactly are you fetching data from your modem? If you are using a blocking method, `QTimer` won't be of help since the event loop has to trigger the connected slot. Most APIs that provide blocking functions have a parameter for a timeout value (this might be what you are looking for)

Comment: Yes I want to execute a blocking method through which I can wait (say 3 seconds) for data . If I receive data in 3 seconds, I will move ahead for some another task else I will quit.
Is there any method except threading?
I am trying to do it with QEventLoop but no idea about it too

Comment: Kindly suggest any helpful method or any relevant example?